# If $p\equiv 1,9 \pmod{20}$ is a prime number, then there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^{2}+5b^{2}$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have to prove that if $p\equiv 1,9 \pmod{20}$ is a prime number then there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^{2}+5b^{2}$.

I consider the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, with ring of integers $A=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. It is easy to check that $\left (- \dfrac{5}{p} \right)=1$ if $p\equiv 1,9 \pmod {20}$. According to this, $t^{2}+5$ has two different roots in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. In consequence, $pA=P_{1}P_{2}$ for certain prime ideals $P_{1}, P_{2}$ with norm $p$. A is not a PID, but if I prove that $P_{1}$ or $P_{2}$ are principal, then I had there exist $\gamma=a+b\sqrt{-5}\in A$ such that:

$p=N(P_{i})=N(\gamma A)=|N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})|\mathbb{Q}}(\gamma)|=a^{2}+5b^{2}$,

and I would have finished. The problem is that I do not know how to prove this. If there is an easier way, please, let me know.

Comment: There is an elementary proof too, suggested by r9m in a comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685958/let-p-be-prime-and-frac-3p-1-prove-that-p-is-of-the-form-p-a23b2?lq=1#comment1439095_685982).

Comment: It's worth asking why the other primes where $-5$ is a square don't count; $p\equiv 3,7\pmod {20}$.

Comment: Thank you barto, r9m's comment solves the problem.

Comment: Hint: there's a paper by David Brink which asserts that if $p \equiv  1 \pmod{20}$ then both $p = x^2 + 20y^2$ and $p = x^2 + 100y^2$ hold or neither holds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure which level to write this at. Here is a completely elementary proof:

As you say, if $p \equiv 1$, $3$, $7$ or $9 \bmod 20$, then $\left( \frac{-5}{p} \right) = 1$. Let $p$ be in one of these residue classes and let $a$ be a square root of $-5$ modulo $p$. Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be the lattice of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \equiv ay \bmod p$. For any $(x,y) \in \Lambda$, we have $x^2+5 y^2 \equiv (ay)^2 + 5 y^2 \equiv (-5+5) y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Since $\Lambda$ has index $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the fundamental domain of $\Lambda$ has area $p$. The ellipse $\{ (x,y) : x^2+5y^2 < N \}$ has area $\pi N/\sqrt{5}$. 
Therefore, taking $N = (4\sqrt{5}/\pi) p \approx 2.85 p$, [Minkowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) shows that $\Lambda$ contains a point $(x,y)$ with $0 < x^2+5y^2 < 2.85 p$. Since $x^2+5y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$, we deduce that $x^2+5y^2 = p$ or $2p$.

So far, the proof works for all four residue classes $1, 3, 7, 9 \bmod 20$. Now note that, if $p \equiv 1$ or $9 \bmod 20$, the equation $x^2+5y^2 = 2 p$ is impossible modulo $8$.

---

You can tweak this proof to be more or less sophisticated, as you please.

**More** If $\left( \frac{-5}{p} \right)=1$ then the ideal $p$ splits as $\mathfrak{p} \bar{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. From the [Minkowski bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound), $\mathfrak{p}$ must have the same ideal class as an ideal of norm $< 4 \sqrt{5}/\pi \approx 2.85$, so either $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal or else $\mathfrak{p} \sim \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{5} \rangle$, in which case $\mathfrak{p} \cdot \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{5} \rangle$ is principal. In the former case, we have a solution to $x^2+5y^2=p$; in the latter case, we have a solution to $x^2+5y^2=2p$ which is impossible modulo $8$. It's not a surprise that the same numbers are showing up -- the above proof is simply this one without mentioning ideal classes.

**Less** If you don't want to mention Minkowski's theorem, you can mimic the pigeonhole proof [here](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/two-proofs-of-fermats-theorem-on-sums-of-two-squares/) that any prime which is $1 \bmod 4$ is the sum of two squares. Consider the numbers $x-ay$ for $0 \leq x < \sqrt[4]{5} \sqrt{p}$ and $0 \leq y < \sqrt{p}/\sqrt[4]{5}$ and proceed as in the link. The inequality isn't as good as you get with Minkowski: You conclude that you can solve $x^2+5y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$ with $0 < x^2+5y^2 < 2 \sqrt{5} p \approx 4.46 p$.

But that's good enough, you just get a few more cases. If $x^2+5y^2=p$, you win. If $x^2+5y^2=2p$, you get a contradiction modulo $8$, if $x^2+5y^2 = 3p$, you get a contradiction modulo $4$. If $x^2+5y^2=4p$ then looking modulo $4$ shows that $x$ and $y$ are even, so $(x/2)^2+5(y/2)^2=p$.