# Show that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p = a^2 + 3b^2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p = a^2 + 3b^2$.

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$.

There exists $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c^2 \equiv −2 \pmod p$.

Define $L=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z^2} \mid x\equiv cy \pmod p\}$ and we know that  $(a,b) \in L \implies a^2+2b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2+2y^2<2p\}$. S has area $\pi p \sqrt{2}$ and there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p = a^2 + 2b^2$ using Minkowski's theorem.

> I have to use a similar argument to the above and use the hint below.
>
> Hint: first prove that $2p = a^2 + 3b^2$ has no solutions for such primes $p$.

Comment: Do you know how Minkowski's theorem is applied to primes of the form $a^2+b^2$ or $a^2+2b^2$?

Comment: Yes I do know they exist.

Comment: So, what do you think?

Comment: Maybe you can use quadratic forms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

The hint can be proven so: $2p \equiv 2 \equiv a^2 \pmod 3$, a contradiction.

**Pigeonhole Principle**

Also, note that since $-3$ is a quadratic residue, this implies there exists such $a$ that $a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$.

By [Thue's Lemma](https://karushib.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/a-nice-lemma-in-congruence/), we get that there exists such $-\sqrt{p}< x,y < \sqrt{p}$ that $x \equiv ay \pmod {p}$.

This would imply there exists such $x,y$ that $0<x^2+3y^2<4p$ and $x^2+3y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

**By  Minkowski's theorem**

$p \equiv 1$ $\bmod 6$, then $\left( \frac{-3}{p} \right) = 1$. Let $p$ be in one of these residue classes and let $a$ be a square root of $-3$ modulo $p$.

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ be the lattice of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \equiv ay \bmod p$.

For any $(x,y) \in \Lambda$, we have $x^2+3 y^2 \equiv (ay)^2 + 3 y^2 \equiv (-3+3) y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Since $\Lambda$ has index $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the fundamental domain of $\Lambda$ has area $p$.

The ellipse $\{ (x,y) : x^2+3y^2 < N \}$ has area $\frac{\pi N}{\sqrt{3}}$. Now take $N =\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\pi}p <3p$

Comment: $2p \equiv  a^2 \pmod 3$ How did you get the  $\equiv 2$?

Comment: @Tony because $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: So $p  \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ implies $p  \equiv 1 \pmod 3$?

Comment: @Tony Yes, that is true. Because $6|p-1$ implies $3|p-1$.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I do this using Minkowski's theorem

Comment: @Tony I never read that proof by Minkowski's theorem thoroughly, but can't you just exchange $2$ for $3$(or so on)? I don't know that much about it. Why don't you see how they proved it for $-5$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069157/if-p-equiv-1-9-pmod20-is-a-prime-number-then-there-exist-a-b-in-mathbbz/1247186#1247186.

Comment: How does the hint help also? Read my op (I have edited some info in)

Comment: @Tony Does this help?

Comment: @Tony Since $x^2+3y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and it is between $0$ and $4p$ this implies $x^2+3y^2 =p$ or $3p$.

Comment: @Tony But $3p=x^2+3y^2$ would imply $x=3t$. So, divide by $3$.

Comment: The last bit should say less than $4p$? And (-3/p)=1 is the same as $a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$?

Comment: No, $\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\pi} <3$. You can do this on a calculator, or with pencil and paper, using that $\sqrt 3$ is about $1.8$ and $\pi$ about $3.14$. This is because Minkowski is slightly more powerful than Pigeonhole. And yes, being a quadratic residue implies $a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod 3$.

Comment: My argument was to use $N=2p$. I have area of $S  = \frac{2p \pi}{\sqrt{3}} <2^2p=4p$

Comment: Can't you say that Minkowski's theorem shows that $\Lambda$ contains a point $(x,y)$ with $0 < x^2+5y^2 \le \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{\pi}p <3p$.

Comment: I am going to edit my OP with my answer for the case $p=a^2+2b^2$, because I don't see why I need the hint for this case.

Comment: Which Hint?   (to reach comment length)

Comment: @Tony My hint is for the problem you asked. Which case are you talking about? Please clarify.

Comment: @Tony It is also right now 3 o'clock in the morning where I live, and I need to sleep. Can't you please tell me later?

Comment: I have edited it in.

Comment: Why does the hint provided in the question help?

Comment: @Tony Ahh! So that's were you were asking! Because it is less than $x^2+3y^2  <3p$, there is also the possibility $x^2+3y^2=2p$. The hint is to remove this case.

Comment: Ah I now see. Thanks a lot.